# Java: Creating a scrolling submenu

Tags: java, menu, scrollbar, submenu

I have a program in which I have a large amount of items listed under a specific submenu.  I am looking for a way to scroll through them, as the menu is now larger then the screen.  Previously i have seen menus in which the top and bottom icons are arrows which, when the mouse hovers over, scroll up or down respectively.  Can someone please explain to me how to do this?  Or else simply how to add a scrollbar to my submenu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option might be Darryl's [Menu Scroller](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/menu-scroller/).